# Как кешировать данные в recyclerview?

Tags: android, кэширование, recyclerview

Допустим у меня есть три Tab-элемента. Я свайпом перемещаюсь от одного таба к другому. В каждом табе создается свой recyclerview. На данный момент при каждом свайпе я делаю загрузку данных с веб. Мне кажется что это не есть хорошо, каждый раз делать запросы к серваку. Как по умному сделать, чтобы данные кешировались что ли. Т.е. просто так не обновлялись данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от очень многих факторов. Как именно восстанавливаете фрагменты при переходе с таба на таб (Если вы используете фрагменты). Вообще в целом делается следующим образом:

1. Для фрагментов. Сохраняйте в `onSaveInstanceState` коллекцию, которая кладется в адаптер, в `onViewCreated` если в `savedState!=null` восстанавливаете.
2. Для вьюх соответственно в Активити или Фрагменте сохраняете мапу с табами и листом коллекций и подставляете, если в ней есть что-то в адаптер, если нет то загружаете с интернета.

А так очень сложно Вам подсказать без конкретного кода